# Last item from database not appearing in listview after adding the item

Tags: android, database

I have a dialogfragment which adds an item to the database and immediately shows it in the listview .

The item added shows in the listview immediately but i don't know why the last item from the database doesn't appear . 
It appears after executing the activity showing listview again , but not just after adding the item through my dialog fragment .

for example , if i have 3 items "a" , "b" and "d" in my listview and database , and when i add "c" , "d" doesn't show in the listview . it only shows after executing the fragment showing listview again .

Comment: I confused by your description: "The item added shows in the listview immediately but i don't know why the last item from the database doesn't appear." If you have a ListView showing "1"-"5" and you add "6", what happens? Also, is this just a typo: `f.getmyListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` should it be getMyListAdapter()?

Comment: if  i have a listview showing "1"-"5" , and i add "4" , "4" is added to the listview and is shown , but "5" is not shown .

Comment: You added an excellent example at the end of your question! It looks like you are not keeping an accurate count in your MyListAdapter, please post this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adapter is using two different lists, the first is the superclass' list populated as `object`:

```
super(activity, R.layout.laundry_list_item, objects);
```

The other is your own:

```
private List my;
```

When you add an item to `my` the superclass, which provides the data for your ListView, does not know of this change until your restart the Activity.

**Try changing** your `Save` button to this:

```
nam = name.getText().toString();
pri = price.getText().toString();
i = new MyItem(nam, Double.parseDouble(pri));
db.addMyItem(i);

MyActivity f = (MyActivity) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("my");
f.getMyListAdapter().add(i); 

// You might need this, but I believe the adapter will update itself in add()
//f.getMyListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

getDialog().dismiss();
```

This will use the superclass' list and avoid your problem.

**Alternatively** with the code you have posted, I believe a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) is a better choice than your own adapter.

In your Fragment:

```
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    // Retrieve a Cursor of every row in the database, "SELECT _id, name, quantity FROM Table"
    mCursor = db.getAllMyItemsCursor();
    madapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.laundry_list_item, cursor, 
            new String[] { "name", "quantity" },
            new int[] { R.id.item_name, R.id.item_qty });
}

public void updateListView() {
    mCursor.requery();
    madapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In the `Save` Button:

```
nam = name.getText().toString();
pri = price.getText().toString();
db.addMyItem(new MyItem(nam, Double.parseDouble(pri)));

MyActivity f = (MyActivity) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("my");
f.updateListView();
```

Hope one of these helps!

Comment: .It's forcing the app to close .it's giving me ClassCastException error in logcat . it says , MyItem cannot be cast to MyList

Comment: I need a little more context, what code are you trying to use?

Comment: the first one . i updated the code above in my question also with yours .

Comment: Goodness your have written a lot of customized code, what is MyList? Could you post that?

Comment: Mylist is used by my custom adapter .

Comment: Ok, I see that the default for `itemqty` is 0 from before, so use: `f.getMyListAdapter().add(new MyList(nam, 0));`

Comment: ok , i got it , but the problem now is that the item added is coming at the end of listview , and i want it at the top .

Comment: It looks like `my` is a public variable from MyActivity, so try: `f.my.add(0, new MyList(nam, 0));`